# Show only posts from one category on custom post type archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type, called Exercises. I also have many categories within that custom post type. I use archive-exercises.php custom loop to display my main exercises page.

Question: How do I modify my archive-exercises.php so it will display only post from specific category?

I managed to get similar effect on my home page with regular posts:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=93&amp;showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify any main query before it is sent to the database, this includes the case of your home page as well. Calling `query_posts` in the template runs a new query, overwriting the original- it's a waste of resources and can produce unpredictable results, particularly with pagination.

```
function wpa_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if( is_post_type_archive( 'exercises' ) && $query->is_main_query() ){
         $query->set( 'cat', 42 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','wpa_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: After I added your code to functions.php, now there are no posts on my domain/exercises/, and when I try to see my posts under Exercises in the Admin back end, they all gone too... when I remove the code it all comes back

Comment: ok I found that I have to check for `!is_admin()` to avoid the issue, however the page is still blank... I do have custom post types with a custom taxonomy, would that make a difference?

Comment: ah sorry, didn't realize `is_post_type_archive` would be true on the admin side. is it a custom taxonomy and not the built in category taxonomy? you need to set [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameters if that's the case, rather than `cat`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a custom taxonomy, so do I apply the tax_query parameters to pre_get_posts , or do I use one of the examples from the [tax_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) page and place it on my archive-exercises.php page?

Comment: btw, thx for advising me to use pre_get_post on my homepage, it worked vonderfully, now I just need to figure out the tax_query :)

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a new query restricted to your custom post type and your desired category/categories...

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'exercises',
    'cat' => 93,
    // some other parameters
);
$exercises = new WP_Query($args);
while ($exercises->have_posts()) : $exercises->the_post() 
    // your posts stuff
endwhile;
```

Comment: I replaced `<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` with your code above and get a blank page with no posts...